# PHPMailer: AltBody (plain text version of message) has always us-ascii charset

Tags: character-encoding, phpmailer

I'm sending messages with **PHPMailer** (version **5.2.22**)

I provide both the HTML version and the plain-text version of the email.

This is the relevant part:

```
 $mailer->CharSet    = 'utf-8'; 
 $mailer->WordWrap   = 80;      
 $mailer->IsHTML( true );       

 $mailer->Subject    = $subject;
 $mailer->Body       = $html;
 $mailer->AltBody    = $text;
```

Despite I specify `utf-8` as character encoding the plain text version is encoded in `us-ascii` (the HTML version is ok).

If I look at the received email source I read:

```
 Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
```

Just before the plain text version of the message.

Comment: I have the same exact issue.  Did you get it worked out?

Comment: This post I just created might be relevant: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/issues/1299

Comment: @gtilflm no, I didn't worked it out. The issue is on `5.2.22` I was hoping a subsequent release would fix it. (I have not migrated to `6.x` yet)

Comment: You might want to checkout @Syncro's reply to my github post above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has been fixed in **PHPMailer 6**

Tested with version `6.0.2`

Still if the plain text version of the message can be represented with the ASCII charset then the encoding is safely downgraded to `us-ascii` but this is **expected behaviour**.